# How do I run an UPDATE query dependent upon the value of another query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a `UPDATE` using `REPLACE` on my MySQL database.

I have a WordPress database table (`wp_postmeta`) containing four fields: `post_id`, `meta_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`.

I would like to `REPLACE` all instances of *denticulata* with *heteropoda* but **only** if that post (i.e. that row's `post_id`) also has a row where the `meta_key` is genus and `meta_value` is *Corydoras*.

For instance,

```
post_id     meta_id     meta_key    meta_value
4           14          breeding    Some stuff here about breeding denticulata
2           15          breeding    Some stuff here about breeding denticulata
4           16          genus       Corydoras
2           17          genus       Apistogramma
```

Only the row with `meta_id` of `14` should actually be altered there, as the rows with `post_id` of `2` aren't from the *Corydoras* genus.

Is this possible? I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
    wp_postmeta AS upd
  JOIN
    wp_postmeta AS chk
      ON  chk.post_id = upd.post_id
SET
    upd.meta_value = REPLACE(upd.meta_value, 'denticulata', 'heteropoda')
WHERE
      chk.meta_key = 'genus'
  AND chk.meta_value = 'Corydoras'
  AND upd.meta_key = 'breeding' ;           -- not sure if you need this line
```

Beware that this will also update `'denticulatas'` with `'heteropodas'` (and any other words that include the string `denticulata`) and that `REPLACE()` is case-sensitive, so `Denticulata` will not be replaced.